# Split string in java for delimiter

Tags: java, android, split, delimiter

My question is that I want to split string in java with delimiter `^`.
And syntax which I am using is:

```
readBuf.split("^");
```

But this does not split the string.Infact this works for all other delimiters but not for `^`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`split` uses regular expressions (unfortunately, IMO). `^` has special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape it:

```
String[] bits = readBuf.split("\\^");
```

(The first backslash is needed for Java escaping. The actual string is just a single backslash and the caret.)

Alternatively, use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) and its [`Splitter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\^`. Because `^` is a special character indicating start of line anchor.

```
String x = "a^b^c";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.split("\\^"))); //prints [a,b,c]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringTokenizer` instead of split

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(Your string,"^");  
while(st.hasMoreElements()){  
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
readBuf.split("\\u005E");
```

the \u005E is the hexidecimal Unicode character for "^", and you need to add a "\" to escape it.

All characters can be escaped in this way.

Comment: ... at which point anyone reading your code has to wonder what on earth it's doing, and look up character U+005E... (Or you need a comment to explain it.)