# how to get particular part of string?

Tags: android, string

```
item1:100

item2:50

item3:200
```

I want to store separate item and price and store them in two different arrays: like in one array ,

```
item1

item2

item3
```

and in another array

```
100

50

200
```

Comment: You question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925726/split-string-in-java-for-delimiter , but you are using : as a delimiter. Also, another quesyion about string split on android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string

Comment: @Coral, I wouldn't call that first one a dupe since it's not really about how to split a string, it's more why `^` doesn't work when splitting. The second one is a much closer match. In fact, too close. I'll have to close-vote on this one as a dupe.

Comment: where is your input string stored ? Is this also a `String` object or is it coming from a file ?

Comment: @sunil string coming from text file stored on remote machine!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
String DELIMITER = ":";

ArrayList<String> arrItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> arrPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then you can just split the string and store the relevant values in the arraylist as:

```
String[] strTemp = "item1:100".split(DELIMITER);
arrItems.put(strTemp[0]);
arrPirces.put(strTemp[1]);
```

Comment: hey thanx buddy woking well!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to separate a string based on another string (actually a regular expression):

```
String str = "item1:100";
String[] words = str.split (":");
```

From there, it's a simple matter of adding `words[0]` to one array and `words[1]` to the other.

The following complete program shows how it's done:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Test {
    private static ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static void addToArray (String str) {
        String[] words = str.split(":");
        items.add(words[0]);
        values.add(new Integer (words[1]));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addToArray ("item1:100");
        addToArray ("item2:50");
        addToArray ("item3:200");

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
            System.out.println ("Item = " + items.get(i) +
                ", value = " + values.get(i));
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Item = item1, value = 100
Item = item2, value = 50
Item = item3, value = 200
```

Keep in mind I'm just doing simplistic string splitting here with no error handling code - you may want to add that if you value robust code, particularly if there's a possibility your input data may not be valid (eg, `"item4:hello"` will generate a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringTokenizer` class for your requirement.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(yourString, ":");
arrayOne[0] = st.nextToken();
arrayTwo[0] = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method for string.

```
     String[] temp = yourString.split(":");
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides the split function in strings. `str.split(":")` for "item:100" returns a String[] with the elements `{"item1","100}`. Now just iterate through the split arrays and build a combined array of the two parts.

Source:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)